# LEFT Outer join +where clause unexpected results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am surprised by the results of a query and am hoping someone can explain it.

The query is kind of large, so I distilled it to the key part:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  A 
INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
LEFT JOIN C ON C.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.Dt = '2016-06-23' 
  AND (B.StatusCode=' ' OR C.Code <> 9)
```

I am getting dates other than 6/23/16 even though I have it in my where clause.  I think it has to do with combining columns in my where clause from a Left joined table and an inner joined table in one expression, but have never experienced this before.

UPDATE: Adding actual query

```
SELECT *
FROM CERT2.cube_mbbal_Daily_Balances BAL
INNER JOIN CERT.Dim_Account A ON A.AccountKey = BAL.AccountKey
LEFT JOIN CERT2.Dim_LoanAccount LA ON A.AccountKey = LA.AccountKey
WHERE 
    (A.AccountClassification IN ('Checking', 'Savings')
     AND AccountStatus IN ('1', '3', '5', '6', '7'))
    OR 
    (A.AccountClassification IN ('Time')
     AND AccountStatus IN ('1', '5', '7'))
    OR 
    (A.AccountClassification IN ('Loan')
     AND (AccountStatus <> 'C' OR RiskCode <> 9))
    AND BAL.DateOfFinancialMeasure = 20160623
```

Comment: move your a.dt condition to inner join and see

Comment: You have over simplified the query.  Your `WHERE` clause cannot return any other date, other than the one specified.

Comment: @techspider agree, i suspect there is a 1 to many on either B or C and that is causing the problem

Comment: Do tables B and C have their own date columns?  The filter will only filter based on the date in table A.

Comment: Can you provide the definition of the tables with a subset of data. You should also provide the results you are getting and the expected one.

Comment: B and C don't have a date column.

Comment: I added the actual query.

Comment: Is this T-SQL? LEFT JOIN is not normally MSSQL syntax for a LEFT OUTER JOIN. ALSO, if this is a outer, your making it into an inner by using a predicate on the outer table.

Comment: @techspider Moving the date to the ON of the INNER join does restrict the date.  I am still not clear on why it doesn't work on the where clause though.

Comment: your actual query shows that the condition for the date is not obligatory, since you have other conditions with `OR` that can get fulfilled

Comment: @Lamak the ORd condition is in parens so the date should be obligatory.

Comment: no, the `OR`s are at the same level that the last `AND`

Comment: You're right! And all this time I thought it was a left join issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AND` is evaluated before `OR`.  It's like you're evaluating `2 + 5 + 7 * 5` and wondering why you're getting `42` and not `70`.

Try:

```
select *
from CERT2.cube_mbbal_Daily_Balances BAL
inner join CERT.Dim_Account A
    on A.AccountKey = BAL.AccountKey
left join CERT2.Dim_LoanAccount LA
    on A.AccountKey = LA.AccountKey
where (
           (A.AccountClassification in ('Checking', 'Savings') and AccountStatus in ('1', '3', '5', '6', '7'))
        or (A.AccountClassification in ('Time') and AccountStatus in ('1', '5', '7'))
        or (A.AccountClassification in ('Loan') and (AccountStatus <> 'C' or RiskCode <> 9))
    )
    and BAL.DateOfFinancialMeasure = 20160623
```

Comment: Yes- I thought the last paren matched the first after "WHERE" but it doesn't.